# How to export photos from a folder in iPhoto, preserving the album structures in the folder?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I have put several albums into a folder in iPhoto. Can I export the photos in this folder, so that the exported directory structure will be like

```
folder/
  album1/
  album2/
  ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File → Export, select File Export and choose a Subfolder Format. This lets you select what you want the directory structure to be.

<sup>Source: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-4921</sup>

Comment: I tried but only to see "None" and "Events". I want them organized by existing albums.